# Print D-Bus introspection tree

Tags: python, dbus

How can I print out a tree of all the available information on D-Bus?

```
*Bus Name
    * Interface
        *Method
            *Signature
    * Interface
        *Method
            *Signature
        *Method
            *Signature
*Bus Name
    * Interface
        *Method
            *Signature
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have created a git repository to demonstrate how to solve this problem:
https://github.com/smokedice/PyDBusTree

The code is rather slow because it doesn't use call backs. If anyone would like to improve the code please post it here, or push to the repository.

Comment: It’s cool that you did, but it’s probably better if we promote a universal set of standard D-Bus tools.

Comment: I personally don't agree. A tool such as D-Feet will not cover every need. I now find this question to be ambiguous as I consider `print` to be associated more with code rather than a tooling. This could be due to language or context.

Comment: [Here](https://github.com/ldo/dbussy_examples/blob/master/introspect_all)’s another option: using an [`asyncio`-compatible](https://github.com/ldo/dbussy) Python D-Bus wrapper.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the dbus debugging tools like [DFeet](http://live.gnome.org/DFeet) to see everything exposed over the DBus in a nice structured fashion.

Comment: D-feet is an invaluable tool and I recommend it to anyone trying to get a holistic picture of what is happening inside the dbus.

Answer (score 1):

As well as [D-Feet](https://wiki.gnome.org/Apps/DFeet) (mentioned in an earlier answer), the [`gdbus` command line tool](https://developer.gnome.org/gio/stable/gdbus.html) will allow introspection of a particular object path on a given unique or well-known bus name:

```
$ gdbus introspect --session --dest org.gnome.Contacts --object-path /org/gnome/Contacts
node /org/gnome/Contacts {
  interface org.freedesktop.DBus.Properties {
    methods:
      Get(in  s interface_name,
          in  s property_name,
          out v value);
      …
    signals:
      PropertiesChanged(s interface_name,
                        a{sv} changed_properties,
                        as invalidated_properties);
    properties:
  };
  …
}
```